# VBA code to select by a cell value and date range to move data from one sheet to another

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am having trouble getting a VBA code that I have adapted for my program to run. There are things in it that I don't understand and I don't know how to fix.
I am trying to filter data from a "Sales" sheet to a Artisan Summary Sheet. Here is the current VBA code I am trying to adapt but I keep getting error 
Code:

```
Sub Filter_Statement()

    On Error GoTo Filter_Statement_Error
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet5

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If ws.Range("D2").Value = "" Or ws.Range("E5").Value = "" Or ws.Range("H5").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in all of the needed information. Customer / Start Date / End Date"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    ws.Select
    ws.Range("ArtisanSummary").RemoveSubtotal
    Set area2 = Sheet4.Range("C2:K100000")

    area2.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy _
        , CriteriaRange:=ws.Range("R4:T5"), CopyToRange:=ws.Range("B10:E10"), _
        Unique:=False
    If ws.Range("B11").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "No available data"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Groupit

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

    Filter_Statement_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Filter_Statement of Module Filters"
End Sub
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Photo of the summary page[image: Page that I need data to enter into]
I am trying to input the date, quanity, code and unit price from the sales sheet. I am selecting by the artisan code in D2 and then the 2 dates in E5 and H5. I have tried running the code with just the month, ex February. But that doesn't work either.
I am also attaching a copy of the sales page where I am pulling data from. the Sales page is my 4th sheet and the Artisan Summary is the 5th sheet[image: Sales Sheet]
I am using excel 2013 to do this.

Comment: Comment out the `On Error GoTo Filter_Statement_Error` line and let us know what error you're getting, and on what line.

Comment: It could be you're calling `Groupit`, although you might have that but haven't included it. You've also got `Set ws = Sheet5`, where you might have meant `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet5")`.

Comment: You state *"I keep getting error"*. Please post the exact error.

Comment: " I have adapted for my program to run. There are things in it that I don't understand and I don't know how to fix." Which are these things? Have you debugged your code? Which are the lines not acting as desired?

Comment: I have spent some time going over the comments. I have commented out the 'On Error GoTo Filter_Statement_Error line. I have removed the Group it line.  Then I ran the Code    Results: Run-Time error '1004': Method 'Range' of Object'_Worksheet' failed. When I debug it the line  wz.Range("ArtisanCode"). Removal Subtotal is highlighted

Comment: @Junno, When I change the Set ws = Sheet 5 to the Sheets ("Sheet 5") I get that line highlighted as the error line.

Comment: @Junno you helped me with another question. I think this code I am trying to work with is too complicated. I need data from "Sales" in columns D,F,G, and I to move to "Artisan Summary" columns B,C,D and E, starting in the 11th row. The data can only move if the date range between E5 and H5 (or S4and T4- I changed the date format- it was a suggestion). The data can only be transferred if the Artisan code in D2 (R5) is the same as the Artisan code on the "Sales" page in Column K. Confusing I know but that is where I am stuck

Comment: @Jen that error means the named range "ArtisanSummary" doesn't exist on Sheet5. Based on the code you provided, that's the only line where that range is used, so it's hard to say why that line is even there in the first place.

Comment: You'll also encounter an error on the AdvancedFilter line because you're trying to copy three columns to four.